# Reverse an equation with absolute values

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this line of code in my program:

```
z = (|(x - s_x)| * sin(rot)) + s_z;
```

I have the `z` variable, I am trying to find out what `x` would be but I can't seem to alter this equation correctly. Every time I try it's wrong. I am getting confused at the `Mathf.Abs` absolute value function.

Here is what I get when I try to rearrange it for x:

```
x = (|(z - s_z)| / sin(rot)) + s_x;
```

Comment: Please write it out in Math, not code.

Comment: Is that how it should be?

Comment: OK, let's look at a simpler problem. Suppose you had $z=|x|$. Can you solve that for $x$ as a function of $z$? (Hint: it's *not* true that $x=|z|$).

Comment: this is confusing, would x just be the value of z but with any sign?

Comment: so basically x = z OR x = -z

Comment: What is "rot", does it just represent an angle?

Comment: @Raskolnikov Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearranging your equation, you get this:

$$z-s_z=|(x-s_x)\sin(r)|$$

To move on you should take into account both the negative and positive solutions:

$$z-s_z=\pm(x-s_x)\sin(r)\\
x=\pm\frac{(z-s_z)}{\sin(r)}+s_x\\
$$

There may be two values of $x$ with which you get the same $z$, thanks to the absolute value.

Comment: what if sin(r) is zero, what do i do

Comment: @Ogen: If $\sin(r)$ is zero then it does not matter what $x$ is, $z$ will always be just $s_z$.

Comment: @Ogen: According to your assignment operation `z = (|(x - s_x)| * sin(rot)) + s_z;`, if $\sin(r)$ is $0$, then doesn't $z$ become $s_z$?

Comment: Yeah you're right I made a mistake, I deleted that silly comment.